# Ruby on Rails error handling

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my production Ruby on Rails app, a 500 error page will show the source code of the controller where the error occurred. Obviously these errors should be handled in the first place, but I am dealing with a ton of legacy code.

Is there a way to create a custom error page that will not reveal my source code when an error is thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you `development.rb` [general configuration](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#rails-general-configuration) of your app, there's a flag

```
config.consider_all_requests_local = true
```

which is `true`, by default, in development. If you set that to `false` (the default in production), you can see the error page that users will see in your production app. This page is in `public/500.html` and `public/404.html` if you want to customize those.

You can also search around for ways to have Rails use ERB to create a custom error page, there are lots of tutorials on that, but I haven't used any and thus can't recommend one.